# After installing habitat on sitecore instance I get value cannot be null in outcomerepository.cs

Tags: installation, sitecore, helix, sitecore-habitat

I installed Sitecore 8.2 through SIM and then added Habitat custom module on it. Executed all the steps given in habitat wiki. When I open the site it gives me error value cannot be null in outcomerepository.cs

Answer (score 1):

on installing mongoDB (through SIM) this error was gone. I referred following link to install mongoDB 
https://www.jflh.ca/2016-09-08-install-mongodb-in-one-click-with-the-sitecore-sim-tool